# Facing Problem in implementing push notification in ionic for web platform

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I want push notification in ionic app , I tried to do it with code push for ionic 
but I can see that it only support Android and ios platform ,

But I want to do It for the website platform too how can I do it ?

Comment: You can use one signal api for that. Plus point is it is free and let u send unlimited notification for free

Answer (score 0):

just use onesignal and u can do it for web, Android and iOS

[link](https://onesignal.com/)

Answer (score -1):

Push notifications are designed to work only on physical devices. You can still notify users on the web via alerts, popovers, etc.